# Retrieve list of all subdomains in search results from Google Search Appliance or Google Search

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

How could I retrieve a list of all domains or URLs represented in google search results for a key term? In this particular case, we have a Google Search Appliance, and I am looking for results on only the domain with the gsa. Optimally, I'd like to retrieve a list of all subdomains of this domain that are returned from a search result.

For example, I search for 'software' using site:example.com 
There are 1500 results. I'd like to retrieve a list of just all subdomains that are returned in the result for that search, so e.g.,
foo.example.com
bar.example.com
...

It'd be great if I could filter the results only for uniques while doing the search, but I can easily do this after retrieving the list.

I'm thinking perhaps this could be done using the 
ajax search API: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets and if it could I'd like to do it in PHP as a first choice.